# Replacing STX and ETB characters, in VB6, using Regex

Tags: regex, vba, vb6

I'm reading COM port results using a vb6 application, and I need to replace some characters, using regex expressions.

The issue is primarily this: I'm getting a lot of unnecessary characters between the "`R`" and "`|`" characters, which I'd like to remove. For this, I'm using the replace function and regex expressions, but it's not working.

This is the code I've written in vb6:

```
objReg.Pattern = "R.*\|"
objReg.Global = True
x$ = objReg.Replace(Text1.Text, "R|")
```

Input Stream:

```
RDA
3|4|
```

which is ("`R`" + `ETB` + "`DA`" + `STX` + "`3|4|`")

Expected Result:

```
R|4|
```

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
objReg.Pattern = "R[^|]+\|"
x$ = objReg.Replace(Text1.Text, "R|")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VNUCwk/1)

The regex will match `R`, then one or more chars other than `|` (with the `[^|]+` pattern) and then a literal `|` char. The whole match will be replaced with `R|`.

You may also use capturing groups with backreferences here if you need to make any more additions to the pattern:

```
objReg.Pattern = "(R)[^|]+(\|)"
x$ = objReg.Replace(Text1.Text, "$1$2")
```

The `(R)` group will correspond to the `$1` backreference and `(\|)` will correspond to `$2`.

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VNUCwk/2).